# Android N - WifiManager addNetwork() fails

Tags: android, wifimanager, android-7.0-nougat

My application works good till Android 6.0 update, after the Android 7 upgrade it starts failing, while debugging found that the `WifiManager.addNetwork()` fails and returns -1.

This happens only when trying to configure TLS network.  Works good with PSK configuration.

Solution:
Code was written to add EAP set phase2 methods, for all the enterprise WLAN, from android N it is restricted to add only to the TTLS and not the TLS. now its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check onruntime permissions. This would help you

Comment: Found the issue it's not with permissions. Code was written to add eap set phase2 methods, for all the enterprise wlan, from android N it is restricted to add only to the TTLS and not the TLS. now its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Same Issue I am facing in android 6.0 and 6.0.1

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192989

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192622

addaddNetwork return -1

below 6.0 works f9 in all device

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
wfc.SSID = networkSSID;
            int pri = getMaxPriority();
            wfc.priority = pri + 1;
        } else {
            wfc.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
            wfc.priority = 40;
        }
```